# Historical Data On Foursquare Venue Changes

Tags: foursquare

Is anyone aware of a way to get historical location info from Foursquare Venues. The problem is that if i look at a users checkin history and one of the venues has changed addresses, there is no way to get the old address / location via the api. For apps built on that data it means when a venue moves all the checkins prior to the move will have the wrong venue info.

Has anyone figured out a way to get that info (obviously this isnt a problem if the user has authed into our service before the change because we have it stored, but after we have no way to access it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to access the old location information, but information should only get strictly better with time. If you have a situation where location information for a venue has become less accurate, you should flag the venue and the super user community will try to fix it.

Comment: The major issue is when venues change. Think of an office "Foursquare HQ" that moves to a new location. All historical checkins from Foursquare HQ will have the wrong address and geodata and that sucks for historical archive and lots of apps that use that.

Comment: If a place changes location, then our super user community has been instructed to close the old venue and open a new one. For example: https://foursquare.com/v/foursquare-hq/4ab7e57cf964a5205f7b20e3 vs. https://foursquare.com/v/foursquare-hq/4ef0e7cf7beb5932d5bdeb4e (your exact use case =)

Comment: Ah that makes a ton of sense. It might be worth updating the UI on the web app to give a prompt when people go to change the address ("Did this venue move? Ok lets close it and create a new one") because we've seen several examples in data of moved venues.